# SwipeListViews 'Null pointer on findViewById'

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

My application uses a main activity and a fragment. I've set up the `swipelistview` under the fragment with contains a custom list view. When executed, the app crashes with the log cat reporting the following error:

> 02-17 15:20:17.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5759): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-17 15:20:17.897:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5759):   at
>   com.fragments.Frag1.onCreateView(Frag1.java:71)

And the following statements lies at line #71 of `Frag1.java`:

> swipelistview=(SwipeListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.example_swipe_lv_list);

I've declared the `example_swipe_lv_list` item inside an XML that is inflated when `getView()` is called.

I'm testing out the example at http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/ But, with fragments.

What might be causing this issue?

Here's full fragment code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.ItemAdapter;
import com.example.ItemRow;
import com.example.R;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.BaseSwipeListViewListener;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView;

public class MyList extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        list.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
    }

    ListView list;
    int index = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState)
    {

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.1);


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);   
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) 

            {

                switch(position)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        mp.release();
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.1);
                        mp.start(); 

                    break;

                    case 1:
                        mp.release();
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.2);
                        mp.start(); 
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        mp.release();
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.3);
                        mp.start();     
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        mp.release();
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.4);
                        mp.start(); 
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        mp.release();
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.5);
                        mp.start(); 
                        break;

                    }
             }
            });
    }
}

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
        Context context;

        public MyAdapter(Context c) {

            context=c;
            list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
            //Initialize them...
            Resources res=c.getResources();
           String[] dialogues = res.getStringArray(R.array.dialogues);
            int[] images={ 

                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,
                    R.drawable.ics,

                    };

           for(int i=0;i<38;i++)
            {
                list.add(new SingleRow(dialogues[i],images[i]));
            }   

        }

public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
       DisplayMetrics metrics =context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
       float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
       return (int) px;
   }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder=null;
        itemData=new ArrayList<ItemRow>();
        adapter=new ItemAdapter(context,R.layout.custom_row,itemData);
        SwipeListView swipelistview;

          swipelistview.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onListChanged() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMove(int position, float x) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
                }

               @Override
                public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));

                    swipelistview.openAnimate(position); //when you touch front view it will open

                }

                public void onClickBackView(int position) {
                    Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));

                    swipelistview.closeAnimate(position);//when you touch back view it will close
                }

                public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

                } 

            });

            //These are the swipe listview settings. you can change these
            //setting as your requirement
            swipelistview.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_LEFT); // there are five swiping modes
            swipelistview.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL); //there are four swipe actions
            swipelistview.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
            swipelistview.setOffsetLeft(convertDpToPixel(260f)); // left side offset
            swipelistview.setOffsetRight(convertDpToPixel(0f)); // right side offset
            swipelistview.setAnimationTime(50); // Animation time
            swipelistview.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(true); // enable or disable SwipeOpenOnLongPress 

            swipelistview.setAdapter(adapter); 

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                itemData.add(new ItemRow("item"+i,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher) ));

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, parent, false);
            swipelistview = (SwipeListView)row.findViewById(R.id.example_swipe_lv_list);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coloria);
            holder=new MyViewHolder(row);
            SingleRow temp=list.get(position);

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(temp.image);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else 
        {
            holder=(MyViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        SingleRow temp=list.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(temp.description);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.textView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans.ttf");

        holder.textView.setTypeface(font);

        return row; 
    } 

class MyViewHolder
{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
} 

class SingleRow
{
    String description;
    int image;
    SingleRow(String description, int image)
    {
        this.description=description;
        this.image=image;
    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `getView()` before `onCreateView()` is called or completed (so you cannot use it inside `onCreateView()` as well).

You can use the inflated view to call `findViewById()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_fragment, container, false);
    swipelistview=(SwipeListView)view.findViewById(R.id.example_swipe_lv_list);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will make sure with that. I've added the full fragment code (before making any edits to it). Can you tell me what other parts should be moved? A lot of other statements are related and i'm new to swipelistviews library.

Comment: @sabergeek You need to put `inflater.inflate` at the top, as in my example.